# Missing argument for parameter 'tabSelection' in call Insert 'tabSelection: <#Binding<Int>#>

Tags: swift

I am trying to change tabs via button press and just learning how to use the Swift language. I am a bit confused when it comes what to pass to the `rewardsView()` under `PreviewProvider`. I apologize as I'm sure this is a very basic question but I have tried to figure this out for a few hours as well as search here. The compiler reports

> Missing argument for parameter 'tabSelection' in call Insert
> 'tabSelection: <#Binding#>'

I am still lost.

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var tabSelection = 1
    
    
    init() {
           UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
           UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .white

       }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            homeView(tabSelection: $tabSelection)
                .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill");
                Text("Home")
            }.tag(1)        
            menuView(tabSelection: $tabSelection)
                .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "text.book.closed.fill");
                Text("Menu")
            }.tag(2)
            rewardsView(tabSelection: $tabSelection)
                .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill");
                Text("Rewards")
            }.tag(3)

            profileView(tabSelection: $tabSelection)
                .tabItem {
                 Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill");
                 Text("My Profile")
            }.tag(4)            
            .font(.headline)
            .accentColor(.white)      }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
    
  
        
}


import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct rewardsView: View {
    
@Binding var tabSelection: Int
    
       var body: some View {
                WebViewRewards()
            }
        
       }


struct WebViewRewards: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebViewRewards>) {

        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.test21111.com/")!)

        view.load(request)
    }
}
    
struct rewardsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        rewardsView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your code (without HomeView, menuView, profileView tabs) - it compiles and runs perfectly. What Xcode version do you have? Have you cleaned you project? (cmd+k)

Comment: Version 12.5.1 (12E507), I also cleaned it but it still won't compile.